# containers to use for JTabbedPanes

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtabbedpane

I am developing a math game and I was thinking about displaying the data like so:

1. Display the data that the user is to screencap and send to me, in a JFrame. This data will be displayed in the form of two JTabbedPanes, each tab showing a table (with five rows and 8 columns)
2. Ask the user (via `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()`) if they would like to see a graphical representation of their progress.
3. If they click "Yes", then show them a JFrame with their chart. This JFrame will have a `JMenuBar` with only one `JMenu` with two `JMenuItem`s (an option for both of the two modes).
4. In this new JFrame, display via CardLayout the active JTabbedPane (the FloatMode has four difficulties, while the IntMode has all the FloatMode's difficulties plus Elementary School difficulty.

I know that [multiple JFrames can be bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice), and I was thinking about using [`JSplitPane`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html), but then it might get too crowded (and I wouldn't be able to let the users choose the mode!). Would a `JDialog` be recommended, or would you recommend something else? //I apologize if it sounds like I am asking you all to do some of my thinking for me...

Comment: This is exactly what I will do; I wish this was in answer form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems best suited to a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) with a single control to select between cards (e.g. a `JList` or `JComboBox`, `JSpinner`, menus etc.).

E.G. as seen in this [short example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556), that uses radio buttons in a button group to select the card.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

I might have a potential solution: make the `JMenuBar` universal! That would eliminate the need for two `JTabbedPane`s and thus speed up performance (due to less `Objects` floating around, especially expensive GUI Objects)!

Comment: of course, I would need an uneditable JTabbedPane (or maybe a popup help) stating that the table is only for one mode. I could take this even further by adding a "Help" `JMenu` with only one `JMenuItem`.

Comment: Also, it seems that only the `JTabbedPane` shows. //I have tried making an example where I have both a `JTabbedPane` and a `JScrollPane` (with a `JTable` in it) inside a JPanel. Why is this so?